# How to generate wsdl with package name?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am getting

```
Web service client cannot be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility.
A class/interface with the same name "test.ArcSightLoginServiceException" is already in use
....
```

error when I try to generate java artifacts with a specific package name(package name is "test").

How can I handle this error? Is there anything wrong with my wsdl or its about Netbeans?